# Why does select option using angularJs show first empty option?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html-select

When I reload the page, the first option is always empty. I want the option containing text *Any Make* to be the default select option. Here is the code for my view:

```
  <select class="form-control" id="make" name="make" ng-init="Any Make" ng-model="makeSelected" ng-change="makeChanged()">
      <option value="0" selected="selected"> Any Make</option>
      <option ng-repeat="obj in makeData" value="{{obj.make_id}}"> {{ obj.make_name | uppercase }} </option>
  </select>
```

here is my controller code:

```
.controller("homeController", function ($scope, makeData, $http) {

            $scope.makeData = makeData;

            $scope.makeChanged = function () {
                $http({
                    method: "GET",
                    url: "homeService.asmx/GetModelById"})
                    .then(function (response) {
                        $scope.modelData = response.data;
                })
            }
        })
```

Comment: what is this makeData in your code?

Comment: makeData is returned data from resolve property from routing, i am using ngrouter service provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove ng-init and in your model give default value

```
   $scope.makeSelected = 0;
```

Here is a running fiddle for your code [Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/varunsukheja/hpLys3qk/)

Fiddle for code with dynamic data [Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/varunsukheja/hpLys3qk/2/)

Comment: @Shaur Bin Talib if you find this answer useful mark it as resolved

Comment: its still not solving my problem, can you try with dynamic data returned from $http service?

Comment: what is the use of $scope.modelData = response.data; in your code

Comment: thats a different story, on selection of any option from select dropdown, that function will be called to retrieve new data from web service.

Comment: check this fiddle with dynamic data: https://jsfiddle.net/varunsukheja/hpLys3qk/2/

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't going to use [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions), at least get rid of that `ng-init` since it isn't a function, and in the controller function set `$scope.makeSelected = 0`;

Then you can remove the `selected="selected"` on that initial option, since the angularJS code will be handling what is selected.

See a demonstration below:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .value('makeData', [{
    "make_id": 1,
    "make_name": "cat"
  },{
    "make_id": 2,
    "make_name": "dog"
  },{
    "make_id": 6,
    "make_name": "monkey"
  }])
  .controller("homeController", function($scope, makeData, $http) {
    //initialize the value associated with ng-model on the select list
    $scope.makeSelected = 0;
    $scope.makeData = makeData;

    $scope.makeChanged = function() {
      console.log('makeChanged');
      //$http() request removed because we don't have access outside this domain for AJAX requests.
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="homeController">
  <select class="form-control" id="make" name="make"  ng-model="makeSelected" ng-change="makeChanged()">
      <option value="0"> Any Make</option>
      <option ng-repeat="obj in makeData" value="{{obj.make_id}}"> {{ obj.make_name | uppercase }} </option>
  </select>
  <div>makeSelected: {{makeSelected}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i am using ng router and makeData is returned from resolve property. why are you making your own object? it works with own created object but not with dynamic data i guess. please see my code and suggest a solution according to that.

Comment: i appreciate that, but it works like this and does't work with dynamic data. please try and suggest a solution.

Comment: If that was so critical, then it should have been disclosed in your original question - remember to always create a [mcve]! Please take [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Vy8Ci5beEIu6swDgS1QO?p=preview) and modify it such that the issue can be reproduced. I modified that from the example linked from the [$route](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) documentation and had to update the src of the route script file.

Comment: That answer is basically exactly what I said....it just has fewer words and no snippet example...